# Truffle not deploy updates

Tags: truffle-migration

Truffle not deploy contract updates. `truffle migrate` compiles it but falsely say network up to date.

OS: Windows

Truffle v5.1.39

npm 6.14.5

Answer (score 0):

You can force truffle to re-deploy all contracts with

```
truffle migrate --reset
```

If the problems continue try removing the build/ directory, recompiling and redeploying.

Answer (score 0):

What updates did you do in your contracts? If your changes didn't modify the contract ABI (like input, name and output in functions, new functions, new public variables) truffle will not deploy it, you have to force with `--reset` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the filename is prefixed with a number and is suffixed by a description. The numbered prefix is required in order to record whether the migration ran successfully. The suffix is purely for human readability and comprehension.

!! so the name of migration file must be something like 1_file.js or 2_file.js